# Convert VARCHAR of "a,b,c" to "'a','b','c'"

Tags: sql-server, varchar

i have set of values like `aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee` to `'aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee'`.
what is the best way to do this?

Comment: "To what end?" D: Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: use `REPLACE()`

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If VARCHAR value all have the same format as your example

You could use the following REPLACE()

```
declare @str VARCHAR(1000) = 'aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee'
SELECT '''' + REPLACE(@str,',',''',''') + ''''
```